# Logout functionality with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have created a app with a login functionality. When the user logs in for the first time, his credentials get saved using SharedPreferences. The next time he logs in he is redirected to the 2nd screen directly. I have implemented a logout funtionality. I clear the preferences but when I try logging in from other account, I still get the details of the previous account.

Here is my code:-

Main.java

```
private SessionManagement sessionManager;

sessionManager.createLoginSession(username, deviceUrl, deviceId, endPointHost, deviceName, name , encodedAccountNameToken, hostUrlToken);
```

SessionManagement.java

```
public class SessionManagement
{
     SharedPreferences pref;

        // Editor for Shared preferences
        Editor editor;

        // Context
        Context _context;

        // Shared pref mode
        int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

        // Sharedpref file name
        private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserDetails";

        // All Shared Preferences Keys
        private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

        // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
        public static final String KEY_EMAILID = "email";

        // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
        public static final String KEY_DEVICEURL = "deviceurl";

        public static final String KEY_ENDPOINTHOST = "endpointhost";
        public static final String KEY_DEVICENAME = "devicename";
        public static final String KEY_USERSNAME = "usersname";
        public static final String KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME = "encodedaccountname";
        public static final String KEY_HOSTURL = "hosturl";
        public static final String KEY_DEVICEiD = "deviceid";

        public static final String  KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED = "deviceregistered";
        // Constructor
        public SessionManagement(Context context)
        {
            this._context = context;
            pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
            editor = pref.edit();
        }

        public void createLoginSession(String emailId, String deviceauthurl, String deviceid, String endpointhost, String devicename, String usersname, String encodedaccountname, String hosturl)
        {
            // Storing login value as TRUE
            editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

            editor.putBoolean(KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED, true);
            editor.putString(KEY_EMAILID, emailId);
            editor.putString(KEY_DEVICEURL, deviceurl);
            editor.putString(KEY_DEVICEiD, deviceid);
            editor.putString(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST, endpointhost);
            editor.putString(KEY_DEVICENAME,devicename);
            editor.putString(KEY_USERSNAME, usersname);
            editor.putString(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME, encodedaccountname);
            editor.putString(KEY_HOSTURL, hosturl);

            // commit changes
            editor.commit();
        }

        /**
         * Get stored session data
         * */
        public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails()
        {
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

            user.put(KEY_EMAILID, pref.getString(KEY_EMAILID, null));
             user.put(KEY_DEVICEAUTHURL, pref.getString(KEY_DEVICEAUTHURL, null));
            user.put(KEY_DEVICEiD, pref.getString(KEY_DEVICEiD, null));
            user.put(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST, pref.getString(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST, null));
            user.put(KEY_DEVICENAME, pref.getString(KEY_DEVICENAME, null));
            user.put(KEY_USERSNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERSNAME, null));
            user.put(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME, pref.getString(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME, null));
            user.put(KEY_HOSTURL, pref.getString(KEY_HOSTURL, null));

            // return user
            return user;

        }
        /**
         * Check login method wil check user login status
         * If false it will redirect user to login page
         * Else won't do anything
         * */
        public void checkLogin()
        {
            // Check login status
            if(!this.isLoggedIn())
            {
                // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                  _context.startActivity(i);
            }

        }

       // This function clears all session data and redirect the user to LoginActivity
        /**
             * Clear session details
             * */
            public void logoutUser()
            {
                // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
                //editor.clear();
                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICEURL);
                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICENAME);
                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED);
                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICEiD);
                editor.remove(KEY_EMAILID);
                editor.remove(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME);
                editor.remove(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST);
                editor.remove(KEY_HOSTURL);
                editor.remove(KEY_USERSNAME);
                editor.remove(IS_LOGIN);
                editor.remove(PREF_NAME);
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();

                // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                _context.startActivity(i);
            }

            public boolean isLoggedIn()
            {
                return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
            }
}
```

What might be going wrong?

Comment: usually, SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("cda-preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        settings.edit().clear().commit(); is used to clear sharedprefs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Main Activity does not contain full source .Make sure you call logoutUser method from your MainActivity

call logout function in ondestroy method in the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Call session.logoutUser() in the main.class while you logout

```
Intent z = new Intent(this,main.class);
    z.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("EMP_ID"," ");
        editor.commit();
        session.logoutUser();
        startActivity(z);
        this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the SessionManagement with Context.

```
public SessionManagement(Context context)
        {
            this._context = context;
            pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
            editor = pref.edit();
        }
```

This "context" is not available.